# Can this be done without tables or JavaScript: 100% height wills remaining height of container

Tags: html, css, html-table

Is it possible to make a none table based layout that allows #bottom element to fill 100% of the remaining space left in the parent element without the use of JavaScript?

Here is what works when using tables:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            table{
                height: 100%;
                width: 100%;
            }

            #top{
                background-color: blue;
                height: 200px;
            }

            #bottom{
                background-color: red;
                height: 100%;
            }        
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr id="top">
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr id="bottom">
                    <td></td>
                </tr>            
            </tbody>            
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
    * { padding: 0px; margin: 0px; }
    body {
      height: 100%;
    }
    #main {
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      position: relative;
    }
    #top{
      background-color: blue;
      height: 200px;
    }
    #bottom{
      background-color: red;
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0px;
      top: 200px;
      left: 0px;
      right: 0px;
    }               
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="main">
      <div id="top">
      </div>
      <div id="bottom">
      </div>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

You don't really need #main, I just like to keep my stuff contained unnecessarily.